# Gnome Shell problems when upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, gnome, 12.10, indicator

The upgrade went mainly smooth but I've had some problems with the indicators in the bottom right corner. They have become so big, compared to what they've been looking like in 12.04, and when I click them so I can access the menu, the panel disappears and then later the menu comes up. It works, but it's a weird behavior...

So how do I fix this?

[image: problems]

Answer (score 1):

This is a change in design for gnome-shell 3.6. It's a bit awkward, yes, but the new version of gnome-shell (3.8, to be released in the next 4 months) will change the behavior slightly.

In the mean time, check out https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/495/topicons/

Comment: Also have a look at the release notes: http://library.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-message-tray.html.en

Comment: Thank you! But as you see in the picture the icons are also hidden in their lower part. Is that also a normal behavior?